# Java process builder does not complain about compilation of underlying script

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, processbuilder

Python code, in `test.py` (notice the indentation error, which won't compile):

```
def add_num(a, b):
    print("nums are", a, b)
  sum = a+b
    print("sum::", sum)
```

Java code:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("python test.py arg1, arg2");
Process p = pb.start();

System.out.println("is alive::"+p.isAlive());
```

output:

```
is alive::true
```

Which is little awkward. At least it should say is `alive::false` because the script has compilation issue so the process should not be up but rather it says it is alive.

Although the Python script has compilation issues the java process still continues to run and does not complain. Why is that?

Comment: `start` just starts the process, it does not mean you wait until the process has finished.

Comment: Try to add `waitFor()`.

Comment: See also [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process. Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for things like paths containing space characters.

Comment: Thanks.. but waitFor() is not what I am looking for, I know about that very well. my query is simple:- how come java process can even start at all when the underlying script has compilation issue. Even after polling to the process, it returns "alive".  I think this should be reported as a bug in java community..!

Comment: Starting the java process.. pb.start() should fail immediately in this case and should return is alive::false, given the fact that the underlying script can not compile. java should have that kind of ability, I believe..

Comment: I doubt there is any attempt to compile anything.  You need to invoke that line as `new ProcessBuilder("python", "test.py", "arg1,", "arg2")`.  Unless, of course, the Python source file’s name is itself 25 characters long and contains all of those characters when you examine it in a directory listing, which I doubt is the case.  If you want to see error output, call `pb.inheritIO();` before starting the process.

Comment: @VGR then how would java outputs, is alive:: true, it should have output 
is alive::false, right. cause the process should never start in this case.!! 

by the way, pb.inheritIO() - is that a blocking call.? if yes, then I need to keep this call in a separate thread.

Comment: You are checking `p.isAlive()` literally microseconds after initiating the new process.  The system probably hasn’t even spawned a new process space yet.  And no, inhertIO does not block.  See [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#inheritIO--).

Comment: Thanks. but then, which process this object "p" points to, is it a java process, or the process being spawned.?